# FeathersJS slow to load static content

Tags: express, feathersjs

Feathers/Express is really slow to load static content. Is there any way to speed up without using Nginx? Each request to load an image takes about 3 seconds for a 200-300kb file on a ADSL connection with 20mbps download. I've tried re-ordering the middleware with no luck and I really have nothing else to say but my post is mostly code.

My App.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const compress = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const logger = require('winston');
const hbs = require('hbs');

const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const configuration = require('@feathersjs/configuration');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');

const middleware = require('./middleware');
const services = require('./services');
const appHooks = require('./app.hooks');
const channels = require('./channels');

const authentication = require('./authentication');

const mongodb = require('./mongodb');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express(feathers());

// Load app configuration
app.configure(configuration());

// Host the public folder
app.use('/', express.static(app.get('public'), { maxAge: '30d' }));

// Enable CORS, security, compression, favicon and body parsing
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compress());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')));

// Set template engine
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// Set up Plugins and providers
app.configure(express.rest());
app.configure(socketio());

app.configure(mongodb);

// Configure other middleware (see `middleware/index.js`)
app.configure(middleware);
app.configure(authentication);
// Set up our services (see `services/index.js`)
app.configure(services);
// Set up event channels (see channels.js)
app.configure(channels);

// Configure a middleware for 404s and the error handler
app.use(express.notFound());
app.use(express.errorHandler({ logger }));

app.hooks(appHooks);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Have you tried a plain Express server? If you are hosting it on your home network and access it from the outside there might be a chance that it just takes that long.

Comment: Echoing what @Daff has said, your ASDL setup is 20mbps download and probably a lower upload speed. Host your content on a digital ocean droplet or AWS micro instance to see if your speeds are still as bad.